# Spring OAuth2 token without ClientId and ClientSecret for External Clients

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

We have OAuth token generation using Spring which accepts Username/Password/ClientId/Secret, which works perfect. For External Client we just need input as username and password and generate OAuth Token.

```
<security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
  </security:http>
```

Below is the new code that we need to add, but it is asking for username and password in browser.

```
<security:http pattern="/**external**/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/external/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
  </security:http>
```

Please guide if we can generate OAuth without clientId and internally pass clientId to generate OAuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never generate an OAuth token without a clientId! Oauth2 has 3 ways of creating a token, Implicit, Code, and user/pass. The last should be avoided, since it means that the Oauth client will get access to the user's credentials, and OAuth was built to prevent exactly that. Implicit token are granted using only the user's credentials (typically involving only the browser). In Code-mode the OAuth client received a code (should not be in a browser), which is then exchanged to a Token. The code to Token exchange require that the Oauth client authenticates, using it's clientId and a secret, this is typically done using Basic Authentication.

Comment: Agreed to your point, but what I want to achieve is token generation using internally passed clientId, where user only passes username and password with spring security xml configuration.

Comment: Are you talking about issuing an implicit token? With Implicit grant, the Oauth client will redirect the user's browser to /oauth/authorize on the server. This URL is protected, so the browser gets redirected to the login page and the user authenticates using form based authentication. After the login the browser will be shown the approval page and the use r approves/denies access for the application identified by the clientId. The OAuth client should never see the credentials, only the trusted OAuth server should, otherwise there is no need to use OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is Resource Owner Password grant type which is explained in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3

Resource Owner Password grant type should only be used with the trusted clients. So if the external client you are talking about is a trusted client (Like a native mobile app developed by the same company. ex. Facebook Mobile App), this can be used.

Flow is explained in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.1

The most important aspect of Resource Owner grant type is client should not store user name and password.